# Google-spreadsheet: Filter multiply column to one column

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to do the following:

A:A & D:D & G:G should be copied to X:X  IF E:E="yoga" & F:F="power"

In other words this is what I need:

=FILTER(A:A & D:D & G:G, E3:E="yoga",F3:F="power")

I will appreciate your kind help
Thank you
Alen

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
 =query(A:G,"select A,D,G where E ='yoga' and F='power' ")
```